# bind x:array to property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplateselector

Since I often use `TemplateSelectors` that distinguish between templates based on Type, I tried to write a `TemplateSelector` that has a property to hold the type/template relationship.

I tried to use `x:Array` to set this property in XAML. This does not work since VS complains that `x:Array` is not a class that implements `IEnumerable`, which according to the documentation it should

MSDN:

> But x:Array can also be useful for populating certain properties using XAML that take general collection support interfaces or classes as their structured property content, for instance as IEnumerable.

Here the corresponding code lines

#### TemplateSelector

```
public class TypeMatchDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public TypeTemplate[] Templates { get; set; }

    ...
}

public class TypeTemplate
{
    public Type Type { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate Template { get; set; }
}
```

#### Use in XAML

```
<x:Array Type="ct:TypeTemplate" x:Key="fooTemplates">
    <ct:TypeTemplate
        Type="{x:Type logic:NamedRegisterInformation}"
        Template="{StaticResource RegisterListTemplate}" />
    <ct:TypeTemplate
        Type="{x:Type logic:AddressedRegisterInformation}"
        Template="{StaticResource RegisterListTemplate}" />
</x:Array>

<ct:TypeMatchDataTemplateSelector
    x:Key="foo"
    Templates="{StaticResource fooTemplates}"/>
...
...
<ListBox ItemTemplate="{StaticResource blub}">
```

The used Types and Templates should be correct. If I execute the code I get this Exception at runtime:

> Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Templates' to object of  type
>   'EP3_gui.UI.ContentTemplates.TypeTemplate[]'. Object of  type
>   'System.Windows.Markup.ArrayExtension' cannot be converted to  type
>   'EP3_gui.UI.ContentTemplates.TypeTemplate[]'.  Error at object 'blub'
>   in  markup file 'EP3_gui;component/ui/readmsfrcontrol.xaml' Line 36
>   Position 11.

Any hints where my error might lie?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you making your life so hard? I mean there are many other ways to be a good programmer! I was just kidding.

You can simply write two `"DataTemplate"`s and filter them based on their `"DataType"` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type logic:AddressedRegisterInformation" ></DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="x:Type logic:NamedRegisterInformation" ></DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Why don't you do this? instead of trying to use complicated custom `"TemplateSelector"` that might cause you many problems like the one you mentioned. This way WPF will do all the selection things and you sit, bind an array of `"Object"` to the `"ItemsSource"`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this (I'm pretty new to WPF). Though the question is still interesting, since this way I can't have two controls with different `DataTemplate`s + I would be interested in why the above does not work, since the documentation seems to say that `x:Array` should be usable this way (and according to many examples it seems possible to bind `x:Array` to an array property.

Comment: Using something that is not made for that purpose always cause you unkown problems and put you in a hard life. Also don't trust to the documents with the closed eyes cause sometimes your codes have different behaviors in action, because the situations are different from each other. I've been using WPF since it was released and never needed to use x:Array. Hope I could help you. Cheers

Comment: Thank you again for your comment. Yes, in this case there is a better solution which I'll be using, but I can't see how the code I posted is 'using something not made for that purpose'. It seems to me that `x:Array` was made for the purpose of being bound to array properties. Therefore my comment. Also: If one can't trust the documentation, then it's either wrong or written ambiguously, both things which I don't hope are the case.

Comment: The problem is when you use "StaticResource" to bind a property, you are not **binding** that property to something! It just set that property to the found key value which means there is no runtime type conversion. Try to change "Templates="{StaticResource fooTemplates}"" to Templates="{Binding Source={StaticResource fooTemplates}"" and see what happens. I believe this is the problem because type of "x:Array" is actually 'System.Windows.Markup.ArrayExtension' (as already mentioned in the exception text) that ofcourse cannot be converted to the array of Template ("Template[]").

Comment: If your problem was not fixed, let me know what happened. I'll gladly help you through this way. :) I think you got my point about the runtime type conversion and you know why it's happening now. Cheers

Comment: I got the problem fixed after your answer, just the reason why it did not work eluded me, thats why I was asking. Thank you very much. Btw. you should maybe copy your explaining comment into your answer, reasons are always interesting...

Comment: @AndreasWallner Happy to hear that and thank you so much. Your welcome. ;) I think flagging the comments as useful would be enough and I can't do that on my own comments! :D Cheers bro.